# Good idea to put bug numbers in a comment in the beginning of the source file?

Tags: version-control, development-process, source-code, comments

Is it a good practice to put bug numbers in the file itself inside a header comment?

The comments would look something like this:

```
 MODIFIED    (MM/DD/YY)
 abc 01/21/14 - Bug 17452317 - npe in drill across in dashboard edit mode

 cde 01/17/14 - Bug 2314558  - some other error description
```

It seems helpful, but is it considered bad practice?

Comment: The question I'd ask is "What can you do with embedded bug numbers that you can't already do with your bug database?" I can't think of any actual use cases.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123936/do-you-use-special-comments-on-bug-fixes-in-your-code

Comment: @M.Dudley: "*What can you do with embedded bug numbers that you can't already do with your bug database?*" - oh, that's easy: You don't have a **direct** connection from code to bug entry. Especially you can't see it without first starting a "svn blame" or whatever CVS you are using. Of course, it's not a life or dead question, but I'm appreciate having at least the bug # as a reference along with the code in such cases, where the problem is not obvious or requires some more explanation.

Comment: @JensG That's why you put it in the commit message, and a `log` on the file will give you pretty much the exact same thing, but without cluttering up the file...

Comment: When cluttering can prevent me from the click orgies, I prefer what you call cluttering. Also, the question I referred to was about what I can't do without it: Just read the damn number, exactly where I need it. Of course I don't think of the file header - lengthy file comment headers are the real clutter.

Comment: @JensG And when you have corrected scores or hundreds of defects on a particular file? The obvious answer is that you periodically clear out the stale IDs, but then you are back to grepping the VC log...

Comment: @dmckee: ... and if you read again, you will notice the condition "*such cases, where the problem is not obvious or requires some more explanation*". Furthermore, I don't want to convince you, there is room for next to any preference on this world of ours. I just answered a question and added some thoughts, why and in what cases I personally find it useful.

Comment: I've worked at a place where they did essentially this (including logging who made the change, and project number, even though that was present in the source control system).  On some files this got to be as long as the actual source code (or a significant portion thereof).  Oh, and the format had changed multiple times, and some of the comments made reference to things that no longer applied... Didn't help that this was RPG, and we were using Turnover.  I was much happier when we moved to Java and SVN, and left that behind us.

Comment: That's the part a source code management is good for. This belongs into commit messages and NOT into the code itself!

Comment: This question is the subject of the Ars Technica article *[Should we list bugs in the header of a source file?](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02)* (published 15 days after this question was posted).

Comment: I reverted some changes that were made because they changed the meaning of the question. The original question asked about keeping a log of PAST bug fixes in the file, while the changes made for Ars Technica changed it to refer to CURRENT bugs that have not yet been fixed.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I've seen this done before, both manually by authors and automatically by scripts and triggers integrated with version control systems to add author, check-in comment, and date information to the file.

I think both methods are pretty terrible for two primary reasons. First, it adds clutter and noise to the file, especially as these comments age and become irrelevant to the current state of the file. Second, it's duplicate information from what's already maintained in the version control system, and if you are using a modern version control system that supports change-sets, then it's actually losing information about changes.

If anything, consider integration with your defect tracking system. Some tools allow you to link a defect or task ID number in a check-in comment to an item in the tracking tool. If you have all of your defects, enhancement requests, and work tasks in the tool, you can provide linkage that way. Of course, this comes with the downside of a dependency on those tools for the project.

Comment: "and if you are using a modern version control system that supports change-sets, then it's actually losing information about changes." - can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Geek I'm not sure what to explain. If you look at a file that references a bug ID number, you don't see other files changes as a result of that same defect unless you search the files. That's what a change-set is - a collection of files checked in together.

Comment: I would also add that if you move to a new bug tracking system then those numbers all become instantly worthless. I've run into that at my current job where some comments have numbers from bug tracking software that hasn't been used in 10 years.

Comment: So after changing to the new bug tracking system, they become as useful as if they were never there. But assuming they provided some value at some point, and provides no negative value now, why not do it?

Comment: @17of26 – I'd imagine you could link old bugs/issues to new ones, if thru no other mechanism than as a comment like "old issue tracker bug 1234".

Comment: @KennyEvitt No, because that would require modifying old commit messages.  It's part of the reason I prefix all my commits with `<tracking system> #<case number>, ` - so at least future readers don't go looking in the wrong system, preemptively avoiding that problem

Comment: @Izkata, I was referring to adding a comment in the new issue tracker, not version control. But I thought of another way to avoid the issue – retain the issue/case/bug numbers when migrating; surely that's usually pretty easy, if the issues/cases/bugs themselves are migrated between issue trackers.

Comment: I once opened a file in which there were so many bug notes in the file that the code didn't begin until well past line 2000. Terrible idea.

Comment: @KennyEvitt Still not helpful since the old bug tracking database is probably long gone.  I just don't think the link is useful in the first place.  If the change requires a comment, then the information you want is *why* the change was made.  Just put the explanation text in the comment rather than using an indirect reference.  Much better than making the reader go digging through a bug tracking system.

Answer (score 42):

There is exactly one case where I would do this, namely as part of a warning for future programmers: "Don't call function `foo()` here directly; this has caused bug #1234, namely ...", and then a short description of the bug follows.

And if the code has changed in a way that there is no temptation to call `foo()` directly, remove that comment. It would only irritate and blow up the code.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit of a hardass, but if `foo()` shouldn't be called directly, then the code should be structured in such a way that it can't be.

Comment: Oh, I tried to write *something* as an example, to make the text more concrete - don't take me too literally. A better case would be a case where you used an external library, and the function you would normally use for a specific purpose had a bug. Then a comment "Don't call `foo()` here" would be reasonable.

Answer (score 15):

It is an altogether horrible practice. It adds effort in order to achieve an effect that is pure duplication; in other words, the only thing that it adds over just using commit logs is the possibility of creating inconsistency. Your source files become cluttered with unlimited amounts of stuff that you never look at.

The only upside I can discern at all is that you could reconstruct the source history without access to the version control, e.g. when studying a printout. But very few people are competent enough to follow the intricacies of software development, while simultaneously unable to understand version control.

Comment: How many bugs exactly do you think are possible in one file and if there are that many its probably time for a rewrite.

Answer (score 11):

No.

That's what people did before they used a version control system (i.e. when source code was just backups in zipfiles).

Comment: which was a version control system of sorts (and one I've seen used operationally in software houses as short ago as 2006, and no doubt is in use somewhere today).

Comment: @jwenting I've seen questions on this very site from people unfortunate enough to currently be working in shops where that is current practice :-(

Comment: We use a great source control system.  No one but me puts comments in when checking in code.  <shrug>

I comment certain things (like PLSQL that isn't always tracked by SCM).  I comment my code to explain, but never tie it back to particular bugs, but I always reference bugs in SCM commit comments when I check in.  Hopefully eventually someone will appreciate it.

Answer (score 10):

It is, IMHO, a very bad idea. After revision number 100, you will have 90% comments and 10% code. I would not consider that as clean and readable.

The only point in this I see is when you have to interchange your code between SCCs and, for whatever reason, you cannot transfer the history between the two systems (but even when you save the history comments that way, you will loose the diff history as well, so saving the comments will only help you a little).

Answer (score 9):

I see that everyone is opposed to the idea and gave a historical reason (pre source control era) of why people were doing it.

However, in my current company, database developers are following this practice and they additionally tag the bug number around the piece of code. I sometimes find this helpful when you see a bug in the code and you can instantly find out the bug fix that introduced this issue. If we don't have that information in my database package it certainly won't be easy to find the root cause of that implementation.

Yes, it clutters the code, but it helps in finding the reason of why that piece of code is there.

Comment: Absolutely. Sometimes I have the slight feeling, that programmers are horrified by redundancy, so they avoid having the same information accessible through different ways. That's very interesting, because programmers are typically also horrified by bad performance and therefore use caches in their programs. But caching bug numbers in the code next to the place where they are most useful is considered bad? Mmmh.

Comment: There's often another way to get that information (on the project I'm working on, it would be `right click > Team > Show Annotations` to get the git blame of the current file), but the difference is, with comments there is discoverability -- they can jump out at you -- and with annotations, you have to consciously decide to go looking for them.

Comment: Think, decide, click, click, click, scroll. That's why I said "caching in code". If it's there, I just see it.

Comment: @JensG Interesting point of view.  Caches can improve performance but they also have a carrying cost.  If the cache has to be filled, updated, invalidated, flushed and so forth by redundant human effort I'd question the cost-benefit ratio, especially considering how terrible humans are at keeping such denormalized constructions in sync.

Answer (score 6):

One of the points in the [Joel test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) is

> Do you have a bug database?

Such information might be kept in a bug database if you think they're important, but they would only be noise in comments.

Comment: See the example in the question - the comments would reference the bug database...

Comment: @Izkata But that's the point. The database itself may have a "comment" field with the comment. The question is not about having a bug database or not, but about whether keeping that in the source file is a good idea. I think, even if they are comments, they should be kept in the database itself because that's what it's for.

Answer (score 6):

I think you have two problems here. First, why should you purely rely on the diff when most systems allow you to enter revision comments? Like good code comments, you discover why the change was made and not just the change itself.

Second, if you have this capability, make it a good practice to put all of them in the same place. There isn't any need to look through the file for marked out lines of code that are no longer needed. Comments inside working code are there to tell you why it is coded this way.

Once you put this into practice, the habits formed make the code base easier to work on for everyone.

Associated bug and feature tracking along with why you're changing this file, can give you an idea about how deep you need to dig into the history and possibly looking at the diffs. I had a request to "Change back to the original formula." I knew right where to go within the revision history and only reviewed one or two diffs.

Personally, remarked out code looks like a work in progress for a problem that is being solved by trial and error. Get this mess out of production code. Being able to easily slip lines of code in and out only makes it easier to be confused.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no VCS with commit messages, and no bug tracking system with an option for you to leave comments, it's one option, and not the optimal one, to keep track of changes.
Better to have a spreadsheet with that information, or if you're in an environment without such "luxuries", a text file sitting somewhere near your sources.
But I'd strongly recommend if you're in such an environment to start building a case towards investing in a VCS and bug tracking system :)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a good practice to track your bug fixes as comments in the code. This only generates clutter.

I'll also say the same for the copyright message that you mentioned. If no one outside your company is ever going to see this code, there's no reason to include a copyright message.

If you are using version tracking software ([Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion), etc.), then you should include those notes in your commit messages. No one wants to dig through the headers of every code file to generate release notes or see an overview of what changes were made. These change logs should all be stored together, either in your version tracking history, your defect tracker, or both.

If you're looking for a good read on this subject, I recommend chapter four of [Clean Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882).

Comment: Copyright notices are also there to (slightly redundantly) put employees on notice that the file belongs to the employer. And perhaps discourages illegal sharing (even by employees), judging by how many people seem to think that copyright only applies if there *is* a notice.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are other elements to this discussion that are often forgotten but are cases where some revision comment is expeditious to a team.

When working in a team environment with a shared code base and where several team members are potentially working in the same areas of code, putting a short revision comment in the correct scope (method or class) indicating a change was made can be very useful for quickly resolving merge or checkin conflicts.

Likewise, when working in an environment where several (feature) branches are involved, it makes it easier for a third person (build master) to identify what to do to resolve potential conflicts.

Any time you have to get away from the IDE and ask someone why they changed something, it is disruptive to both team members' productivity. A quick note in the correct scope can help abate or eliminate most of this interruption.

Comment: question is about comment in the beginning of the source file,  right after copyright message - this has nothing to do with comments in the narrower scopes

Comment: All of the answers here are talking about just that, though. If I make significant changes to the entire class file (reorg or formatting fixing), would I not comment the class file as the scope?

Answer (score 2):

Keep this in mind - the code is often around longer than the tools that support it.  Said differently, the issue trackers, version control and all the other scripts will evolve over the course of development.  Information gets lost.

While I do agree, file clutter is annoying, opening a file and understanding its history without resorting to using the tools, has always been very helpful - especially if I'm maintaining the code.

Personally, I think there is room for both the tools and in-code log.

Answer (score 1):

I know [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) doesn't do this and the simple answer is "why on earth *would* it go there?"

It's a less modular design in general. Under this solution, now files are some mix between content and meta-data. [Amazon S3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3) is another example of a service for storing files that doesn't add [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) front-matter or the like to files.

Any consumer of a file is required to process it through the version control system first. This is tight coupling, e.g. your favorite IDE will break if it does not support your VCS.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely wouldn't put such information at the start of the file - usually such a thing belongs into a ticket system.

There are however some cases where references into the ticket system and / or other documentation make sense. For instance, if there is a lengthy explanation of the design, or description of alternatives. Or information how to test things, or explanations why it was done exactly that way. 
If that's short, it belongs into the file itself; if it is long and / or is about a larger picture, you'll probably want to put it somewhere else and reference it.

Comment: this does not seem to add substantial value to what has been already posted in prior answers

Answer (score 0):

The project I am currently assigned to at work had this type of bug numbers list at the start of every file; however, none of the developers still on the project append to it anymore. Most of them think it's a useless waste of space, as it is far inferior to tracking bug commits to a file using our version control system.

In certain critical files that have undergone many fixes and enhancements, these lists have become so large you have to scroll past them to get to the code. When greping these lists can result in several false positives as a short bug title or short description is listed with each.

In short, these lists are at best useless and at worst a massive, chaotic waste of space that makes code harder to search through and locate.

Answer (score -1):

Any bug information directly associated to a piece of code, become irrelevant when the integrity of the whole change is modified by a successive fix.

It used to be common to add info in the function summary when we had to rely on external tools (say javadocs) to create release notes from the code.
It is mostly useless or redundant with modern version control tools.

It could only make sense as a comment in a very modular piece of code, if one has to resort to some obscure or non stellar coding which future developers would be tempted to change - unaware of the reason behind it - like in a workaround to a library bug/shortcoming.